# Binarization of an image with desired threshold

Tags: matlab, loops, image-processing, binary

I am trying to make a function, that would be given a grayscale image, which it will binarize depending on the set threshold. I've been at this all day but no success.

Here is the code I implemented. With the image being a specific image; Not a variable.

```
function [ output_args ] = thresholdImg(X)
A=imread('car_gray.jpg');
B=zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2));
for l=1:size(A,1)
    for m=1:size(A,2)
        if(sum(A(l,m,:))>X)
            B(l,m)=1;
        end
    end
end
B=logical(B);
figure,imshow(B);
```

I don't want to use `imbinarize`. I want this to be preformed manually, and the code to be as simple as possible. The output of the image looks like it is binary, but when you print the matrix, you see that the values are not only 0s and 1s or 255s

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem appears when you save the image. If you [check the description of `imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#description), you will see that if you want to save your image as binary, you are supposed to choose `BMP`, `PNG` or `TIFF`. These are lossless formats. `JPEG` on the other hand is a [lossy compression format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).

In addition, I made your code very compact, according to [Adriaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39936116/6469393):

```
function [] = thresholdImg(X)
A=imread('car_gray.jpg');
B = sum(A, 3) > X
figure,imshow(B);
```

Answer (score 5):

It'd be faster to get rid of the loop altogether:

```
function [] = thresholdImg(X)
A=imread('car_gray.jpg');
tmp=sum(A,3); % sum along the third dimension
B = zeros(size(tmp));
B(tmp>X) = 1; % Set all values above the threshold to be one
B=logical(B);
figure,imshow(B);
```

Using the following conditions: `A = rand(100,100,3);X=0.6;` we get this picture:

[image]

We see that this is indeed, as we expected, fully binary. Additionally, you can check this by calling `whos B`, which tells us `B` is indeed of type `logical` and hence has only zeros and ones.

```
whos B
  Name        Size             Bytes  Class      Attributes

  B         100x100            10000  logical
```

Comment: What could i be doing wrong?   After I save the results of this loop and the function you showed into a jpg file, and later read it the matrix is not binary.  What could the problem be?

Comment: @RyneIgnelzy you should've told us that in the question statement. Your problem is apparently not in the code you showed us, but in saving it as a jpg. Save instead as bmp or png (tiff would work but is a tad overkill).

Comment: You have no idea how much I was killing my head trying all sort of different looops and i realised after your code that the problem seems to be in saving the image to jpg...any idea why that happens?

Comment: @RyneIgnelzy yes, read erfan's answer. He links to the documentation which states exactly this.